# c# Swagger отображение IFormFile в классе

Tags: c#, swagger, swaggerui

Пробовал добавлять настройки:

```
c.SchemaGeneratorOptions.CustomTypeMappings.Add(typeof(IFormFile), () => new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "file", Format = "binary" });
c.MapType(typeof(IFormFile), () => new OpenApiSchema() { Type = "file", Format = "binary" });
```

Метод контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadDays(Days Parameter)
```

Класс используемый в параметре:

```
public class Days
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IFormFile ExcelFile { get; set; }
}
```

В итоге в Swagger отображается параметр "Year", а параметр файла отсуствует.
Есть возможность  настроить с такими параметрами визуальное отображение в Swagger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил к параметру метода контроллера [FromForm].
Получилось:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadDays([FromForm] Days Parameter)
```

И Swagger начал отображать нормально оба параметра.